# Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}, a < b$. Prove that if $\;v \in H^1_0(a,b),\,$ then $\,v(a)= v(b)= 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $a < b$.

How do we prove that if $\;v \in H^1_0(a,b),\,$ then $\,v(a)= v(b)= 0$?

By definition, $H^1_0(a,b)$ is the completion of smooth compactly supported functions on $(a,b)$ with respect to the $H^1$ norm.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in one dimension the Sobolev embedding theorems imply that $H^{1,2}(a,b)$ is continuously embedded into $C^0$ (even $C^{0,\alpha}$ for appropriately chosen $\alpha$). This implies in particular that approximation in the $H^{1,2}$ norm implies uniform convergence hence -- of course --  pointwise convergence.

Edit (responding to questions in comments): it is actually easy to see in the case you are looking at: suppose $f_n$ converges in $H^1$ to $f$, where the $f_n$ are smooth with compact support in $]a,b[$. This, first of all, implies that the $f_n$ can be extended continuously to $[a,b]$ by setting $f_n(a)=f_n(b) =0$.

Then (by the fundamental theorem of calculus) $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| $ equals
$$|f_n(x)-f_m(x) - (f_n(a)-f_m(a))| =| \int\limits_a^x (f_n-f_m)^\prime(t)dt| \le (b-a)  ||f_n-f_m||_{H^1}             $$
So you get uniform bounds on the difference of the functions. Hence the limit $f$ is continous and allows continuous extension to the closed interval $[a,b]$ where it has to attain the same value as all the $f_n$, namely $0$.

Comment: I dont't understand, what's the relation between convergence and my question? Please.

Comment: @hin $H^{1,2}$ -- I assume you are talking about the Sobolev space -- is the closure of the set $C^\infty_0$ with respect to the $H^{1,2}$ norm. So each element is the limit of a sequence in $C^\infty_0$ in that norm. My answer says that for such a limit the boundary values (which are identically zero) are preserved in the limit (due to uniform convergence).

Comment: but who is $H^{1,2}$? i talk about $H^1_0(]a,b[) = \overline{\mathcal{D}(]a,b[)}_{H^1(]a,b[)}$

Comment: $H^{1,2}$ is the Sobolov Space of functions which are square integrable and the derivative of which are square integrable. $H^1$ is often used as well to denote this space, since the one with index 2 (for square integrable) is the one which is most commonly used.

Comment: @hin I added an explanation to my answer, maybe that helps you to understand what it is all about.